# SproutForms: User permissions to edit form settings not being honored

Tags: plugin-sproutforms

I am trying to setup a user permissions such that only a specific user group has permissions to create and edit SproutForms.

When editing the permissions for a user group, there is an option for SproutForms labeled `Edit Form Settings`. If I leave this setting unchecked, but check the `Access SproutForms` under the `General` heading so that the user may view form submissions, a user in this group is still able to create and edit forms.

Is this a bug? Running SproutForms version `2.3.2`.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this as well. I only wanted to client to view the submissions but not edit the actual forms. I don't believe it's a bug they just didn't give it a separate permission.

Here's my workaround:

I edited all three sproutform templates in the _layouts folder.

- base.html
- elementindex.html
- settings.html

I moved

```
forms: {
  label: "Forms"|t,
  url: url('sproutforms/forms')
}
```

within the

```
if currentUser.can('editSproutFormsSettings')
```

Now the "Edit Form Settings" permission includes the actual forms.

Comment: Only problem is that when the plugin gets updated it will probably overwrite the code.

Answer (score 1):

[Sprout Forms](https://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/forms) v2.5.0 adds improved support for permissions. These permissions can be set per user group and now include:

```
- Manage Forms
- View Form Entries
-- Edit Form Entries
- Edit Settings
```

To allow a particular user group to create and edit forms, they will need the `Manage Forms` permission.